# Why sorting an ascending array (1~100,000) with std::sort() is faster than just using for loop 100,000 times

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, stl, arr

I know that `std::sort` has a very high performance, as far as I know it uses `Introsort` (`quickSort`+`insertionSort`+`heapSort`), but in my tests I found that: "sorting an ascending array (1~99999) with `std::sort()` is faster than just using for loops 100,000 times".  Although `std::sort` is fast, at least it needs to traverse the entire array. I think this is not possible (std::sort is faster than just for loops with the same number of loops and array lengths). I am very confused, who can tell me what is the principle.

It's hard to understand only in `MacOS`, I also tested it in `Linux (Centos 7.6`) and the results are expected.I want to know what Mac and Xcode did to it.

- Environment：

  1. MacBook Pro (MacOS Mojave 10.14.6), Xcode
  2. X86_64（Centos7.6）, clang++
- Test Code：

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <sys/time.h>
  #define LENGTH 100000
  int *  order_arr(int lo, int hi, int reverse) {
      int *arr=(int *)malloc(hi<<2);
      if (reverse==0) {
          for (int i = lo; i < hi; ++i) {
              arr[i]=i;
          }
      return arr;
      }else{
          for (int i = lo; i < hi; ++i) {
              arr[i]=hi-1-i;
          }
          return arr;
      }
  }

  int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

      // ---- Create an ascending array: 0~99999
      int * order_array = order_arr(0, LENGTH, 0);
      //------------------------------------------------------------------
      timeval starttime,endtime;
      gettimeofday(&starttime,0);
      //----------------------------------------------------------------------start_time
      // ---- STL sort
  //    std::sort(order_array, order_array+LENGTH);

      // ---- Only for loop 100000 times
  //    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; ++i) ;
      //----------------------------------------------------------------------end_time
      gettimeofday(&endtime,0);
      double timeuse = 1000000*(endtime.tv_sec - starttime.tv_sec) + endtime.tv_usec - starttime.tv_usec;
      std::cout<< (timeuse/=1000000) <<std::endl;

      return 0;
  }
  ```
- Running results:

  1. MacOS(Xcode):Unreasonable, with or without optimization, std::sort() sorts the array, this time should not be less than only for loop(without optimization 0.000203 s).

     - optimization: `clang++ test.cpp -std=c++11 -o -O3 test`

       1. `for (int i=0; i<LENGTH; ++i) ;` : 0 s
       2. `std::sort(order_array, order_array+LENGTH);`:0.000118 s
     - No optimization:`clang++ test.cpp -std=c++11 -o test`

       1. `for (int i=0; i<LENGTH; ++i) ;` : 0.000203 s
       2. `std::sort(order_array, order_array+LENGTH);`:0.000123 s
  2. Centos7.6(g++):reasonable

     - optimization:`clang++ test.cpp -std=c++11 -o -O3 test`

       1. `for (int i=0; i<LENGTH; ++i) ;` :0 s
       2. `std::sort(order_array, order_array+LENGTH);`:0.001654 s
     - No optimization:`clang++ test.cpp -std=c++11 -o -O3 test`

       1. `for (int i=0; i<LENGTH; ++i) ;` :0.0002745 s
       2. `std::sort(order_array, order_array+LENGTH);`:0.002354 s

Comment: How did you compile the code? Did you enable optimization? Also you don't **do anything with your data, allowing the compiler to optimize then away at will. Use them.

Comment: Unless you post how you compiled your code (optimization settings), your timings are meaningless.

Comment: @gsamaras No optimization ,

Comment: Benchmarking without optimization is like going to war for peace.

Comment: Run the same tests with optimizations turned on when you build your program.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't know how to optimize the code in Xcode, and in linux `clang++ test.cpp -std=c++11 -o test`

Comment: `-O2` or `-O3`.  You need to show this information if you're going to give benchmarks or ask why certain code is faster than another.  If you ever look around at how benchmarks in C++ are done, you will see the optimization settings the tester is using.  Surprised it isn't specified in the "how to post" section of StackOverflow, since this happens so often.

Comment: Xcode's compiler is just clang, so assuming you have the command line utilities installed you should be able to compile on both platforms the same: `clang++ --std=c++14 -O2 -o test test.cpp` . With optimizations on full-tilt the loop version throws out the loop, leaving a 0ms differential. If you're serious about measuring performance you (a) compile with release-mode optimization, and (b) examine the assembly intermediate if there is still questions.

Comment: Any performance figures you obtain without optimisations are utterly irrelevant. They are just meaningless noise.

Comment: What does "using for-loops 100,000 times" mean, exactly?

Comment: Also, the optimization settings only affect your code -- the standard library (the code std::sort uses) was built with full optimization.

Comment: @ChrisDodd - std::sort is a template: it's source code that gets compiled along with the code that calls it. It usually has conditional compiles for debug versus release build that uses faster code for release build (at least in the case of Visual Studio).

Comment: The source code for the template just calls (non-template, static) functions in the stdlib.  Most of the code (and most of the runtime) is in the library and optimized.

Comment: It may be helpful to tell your compiler to output assembly in both cases, so you can take a look at how things are implemented.  I believe the relevant command-line option is `-S`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible explanation:

You do not use the contents of the sorted array. clang expands the initialization and the template code inline and can determine that you are discarding the array, so it does not even generate the code to sort it, resulting in faster time than the alternative where it does not discard the explicit empty loop.

Try and make `main()` return the first element of the array to see if it makes a difference.

With your updated question, there seems to be no real issue:

- the timings for optimized builds are consistent, with no time spent in the empty loop and a short time spent sorting the already sorted array.
- the timings for the unoptimized builds are essentially irrelevant as the core of the template code might still be optimized while the simple loop is compiled into naive inefficient code.

You seem surprised by the performance of `std::sort()` on an already sorted array on MacOS. It is possible that sorting is very efficient there on an already sorted array, both in increasing and decreasing order. An initial scan is used to split the array in chunks. With your dataset, the initial scan quickly yields a single chunk that is left as is or is simply reversed.

You can try and analyze the template code, which is available on both platforms either directly in the include files or in the open source libraries.

Comment: After reading your answer, I performed a reverse-array test. After the sorting is completed, I output the entire sorted array. The time is only a little more. 0.000216,This shows that it does sort the array.

Comment: Can you tell me where the std::sort source code can be viewed? The URL

Comment: @Treasone: not for the faint of heart: https://opensource.apple.com/source/libstdcxx/libstdcxx-104.1/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algo.h.auto.html

Comment: @chqrile Thank you very much ^.^ !